# Installing swaggo on windows (swagger + gin)

Tags: windows, go, swagger, go-gin

I am trying to setup swagger for gin-gonic on windows. 
Documentation of swaggo states that I should run:

```
go get -u github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag
```

After installation I should be able to run `swag init` from within the root of my project where I have `main.go`, but the cmdlet states the following:

```
swag : The term 'swag' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is    correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ swag
+ ~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (swag:String) [],  CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How can I add swag to PATH or how should I proceed from here?

Ps, i followed documentation from [here](https://github.com/swaggo/swag)

**Update**: So I did a clean installation of Go on another PC, followed by `go get -u github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag` and `swag` runs right of the bat. Earlier I followed [this](https://revel.github.io/tutorial/gettingstarted.html) tutorial and I might have accidentally messed up my `$GOPATH` on the original PC.

Answer (score 1):

add $GOPATH/bin   to  PATH, for example:

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/.../go/bin

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below article to get swagger on gin

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/tutorial-generate-swagger-specification-and-swaggerui-for-gin-go-web-framework-9f0c038483b5

If you face any issues to get swag use below command to get swag on windows

```
go install github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag
```

Comment: This one works for me. I didn't need to do anything extra. Thank you Vijay

Answer (score -1):

first of all clear your cache

```
-go clean --modcache
```

how to install swagger in go

```
-https://libraries.io/go/github.com%2Fswaggo%2Fhttp-swagger
```

-go to your file path them install the following packages
1-`go get github.com/swaggo/http-swagger`
2-Download Swag for Go by using:

```
-go get github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag
```

3-Run the Swag in your Go project root folder which contains main.go file, Swag will parse comments and generate required files(docs folder and docs/doc.go).

```
-swag init
```

4.Download http-swagger by using:

```
- go get -u github.com/swaggo/http-swagger
```

5-Run it, and browser to
`-http://localhost:1323/swagger/index.html`, you can see Swagger 2.0 Api documents.

And to know the path you are working on type

```
-go env
```

then look for `GOPATH=` there you will see your path

Comment: for more information go here `https://github.com/swaggo/http-swagger`

Comment: also with this  for gin-swagger `https://github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger`